# Сохранение и загрузка изображения из localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите реализовать сохранение изображения в локалсторедж и последующую загрузку в DOM при отправке формы.

Буду признателен, если еще подскажите как реализовать тоже самое только без локалсторейджа, а с Base64 Image

```html
<form class="form-add" method="post" action="#">
    <textarea class="" id="title-add" placeholder="Название"></textarea>
    <input class="" id="img-add" type="file">
    <button class="" id="add-inf" type="submit" value=""></button>
</form>
```

```js
var onFormSubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* должно происходить сохранение значений из title-add, img-add в локал сторедж
    и затем отобразить в низу страницы */
};

$('.form-add').submit(function (e) {
    onFormSubmit(e)
});
```

Comment: значениями в `localStorage` могут быть **только** строки, поэтому при попытка добавить в него картинку напрямую в него запишется что-то вроде "[object Object]"

Comment: картинка это ведь путь, что-то типо file:///Users/fdfdfsf.img

Comment: картинка - это картинка, путь - это путь

Comment: я имел ввиду, что сохранить в локал сторейдж путь до картинке и потом отобразить ее

Comment: так какой все-таки вопрос? сохранить в localStorage? или в Base64 перевести?

Comment: сохранить в localStorage

Comment: @HelpaMnePlz а чем вас не устраивают ответы из [ПОИСКА](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=localStorage) на ruSO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже получить путь к выбранному файлу в новых браузерах невозможно, максимум можно узнать только имя файла.

Для загрузки в base64 можно воспользоваться классом [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), в котором есть [метод readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) как раз и получающий из картинки строку base64, которую можно подставить в атрибут `src` тега `img`, а так же эту строку можно сохранить в [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), так как это обычная строка.

```js
var onFormSubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var img = this.elements['img-add'];
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('selected').src = e.target.result;
  }
  fr.readAsDataURL(img.files[0]);
};
$('.form-add').submit(onFormSubmit)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-add" method="post" action="#">
  <textarea class="" id="title-add" placeholder="Название"></textarea>
  <input class="" id="img-add" type="file" />
  <button class="" id="add-inf" type="submit" value="">Submit</button>

</form>
<img id="selected" />
```